# Multiple Promises: Get back the input that was used to create them

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have an async function `getContextUrl(id: string): Promise<string>` that will return an `url: string` for a given `id: string`. Because the function is async, the `url` is wrapped in a Promise.

I now want to map a resolved `url` to the original `id` that was used. So far I have the following:

```js
const urlMap: {[key: string]: string} = {}; // map to store url->id as key->value
const ids: string = ['foo', 'bar']; // some IDs

const contextUrlPromises: Array<Promise<string>> = ids.map((id: string) => getContextUrl(id));
Promise.all(contextUrlPromises).then((urls: string[]) => {
                            // what do I do here? How can I map back to the `id` that belongs to this  `url`?
                        })

// my getUrl function
async function getContextUrl(id: string): Promise<string> {
    // driver.getUrl is actually the async function from WebdriverIO, but that shouldn't be relevant for my problem
    return driver.getUrl();
}
```

My problem is: once the `urls` are resolved, because of their asynchronous nature, I don't know which `url` belongs to which `id`. As you can see, my approach is to populate a key/value object `urlMap` with the values. But maybe there's a better way...

**Bonus**: I actually only need the first resolved `url` which contains a certain string, so there is room for further optimization because the calls to `getContextUrl()` can stop, as soon as such an `url` has been resolved. Something like this:

```js
const contextPromises: Array<Promise<{ id: string, url: string}>> = ids.map((id: string) => getContextUrl(id).then((context: { id: string, url: string}) => {
  if (context.url.includes("foo")){
    return context.id;
  }
});

Promise.race(contextPromises).then((firstId: string) => {
  // do something with the first ID whose URL contains "foo"
})
```

Comment: `urls` and `ids` will have the same index. `urlMap.set(urls[0], ids[0]`

Comment: @ritaj - `urlMap` is an object literal - not a Map object.

Comment: if `driver.getUrl()` already returns a promise, there is no reason to wrap it in an `async` function. The return statement already provides the promise and `async` is duplicative.

Comment: But, one solution would require the use of `async`/`await`: You could return an object that contains both `id` and resolved `url` like so `let url = await driver.getUrl(); return {id:id, url:url};` When the promise resolves you'll have both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data returned by `Promise.all` are in the same order as the data used to called it.

In the following example, we are going to use the index of the `url` to find the related `id`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=1#code/PTAEFsEMAdQFwPagM6IE4FNQFc0BsBaAPgEsATUSZUAawwE9iA3SPbDAKAGMEA7VHPgCyMAFygA3h1CgA2nXrjUaErwDmAXSVwV6gNwcAvqAC8kw3tAcOIFAnBYAkgBFk3PgPLJtutbI2mcgDkAGYICEEANKBBAEaQaEEaBjZg4PSgahhwAKr4oCHYvFxwJHwchcWlfJnZAMJ8cBgAHrn4ABTkPqpqAJTiAApo9iTIGAA8yj1EktKgmHC4vKC8GADuoEMjY+3tmMgIeEwYvaYzUjIyY3AAKiQOCNhwu6cmM-uHx+2h4UG90QAGXoGGSGYFGaw8fhwUBQpqtPJ4LbgUYYbybYYosaTHTTfyBLwAOig0F2XRQuPUrxmWTgDV48LaeE6ZF64I47So9GK7WpsxkUIEuDw6Km6nxZkga0gJBhyNRhNYzLhLSZ8rGyHBMjmwuQhLCaAAopAuAALXbNaLNEh8i6XQWHDCEvAINTtAAGN1NWF1oAAJBJmsZYhgXepqIh4N7QOR-RIvLJrRpDO6taAwQYwbyUhwgA)

```
// map to store url->id as key->value
const urlMap: {
  [key: string]: string;
} = {}; 

// some IDs
const ids: string[] = ['foo', 'bar'];

// my getUrl function
function getContextUrl(id: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 0);
  });
}

const contextUrlPromises: Promise<string>[] = ids.map((id: string) => getContextUrl(id));

(async() => {
  const urls: string[] = await Promise.all(contextUrlPromises);
  
  urls.forEach((x, xi) => {
    console.log(`The urls ${x} belongs to the id ${ids[xi]}`);
  });
})();
```

---

In JavaScript :

```js
// map to store url->id as key->value
const urlMap = {}; 

// some IDs
const ids = ['foo', 'bar'];

// my getUrl function
function getContextUrl(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('foo'), 0);
  });
}

const contextUrlPromises = ids.map(id => getContextUrl(id));

(async() => {
  const urls = await Promise.all(contextUrlPromises);
  
  urls.forEach((x, xi) => {
    console.log(`The urls ${x} belongs to the id ${ids[xi]}`);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This got me one step further (I used @Erik's solution, but yours is good, too).. But what if I want to optimize further by stopping the calls to `getContextUrl` as soon as the resolver URL includes a certain string? I tried `Promise.race`, but the promises remain all in pending state. I updated my question under "Bonus" for you to see what I did.

Answer (score 3):

In the return statement of `getContextUrl()` you can return an object containing both the `id` and the `url`. In the example below I have formatted it similar to `urlMap`. This way you can add it to the object without any modification.

```
let urlMap: {[key: string]: string} = {}; // map to store url->id as key->value
const ids: string = ['foo', 'bar']; // some IDs

const contextUrlPromises: Array<Promise<string>> = ids.map((id: string) => getContextUrl(id));
Promise.all(contextUrlPromises).then((urls: string[]) => {
                            urlMap = {...urlMap, ...urls};
                        })

// my getUrl function
async function getContextUrl(id: string): Promise<string> {
    // driver.getUrl is actually the async function from WebdriverIO, but that shouldn't be relevant for my problem
    return {[id]: driver.getUrl()};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This got me one step further. But what if I want to optimize further by stopping the calls to `getContextUrl` as soon as the resolver URL includes a certain string? I tried `Promise.race`, but the promises remain all in pending state. I updated my question under "Bonus" for you to see what I did.

Comment: I am definitely no expert, but as far as I know there is no native support to cancelling a Promise in Javascript. You could reject them before they are resolved, but I don't have a ready-to-use snippet for you in this case.